# Sencha Architect 4.2 - How to painlessly change <title> in generated index.html

Tags: sencha-architect

I'm working on a project that has gone through a name change.  I need to change the
***<title>*** property in the generated index.html.  Normally, changing the name property on the application from Sencha Architect 4.2 has far-reaching effects.  *Simply changing the "name" of the app from within SA will affect namespaces, file and folder names, and even source control history...*

Since the index.html is generated every time a build is performed, any manual changes made to this index.html get overwritten with the build.

The workaround I have so far is to hook into the application method and manipulate the DOM directly.

```
launch: function() { 
...
Ext.getDoc().dom.title= 'My Application Name';
...
}
```

Is there a way to feed additional configuration options for the index.html so that the build process properly uses the value we want?  I would ideally like to remove this hack from my production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Application you can set the **title** config option.

```js
// @require @packageOverrides
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});


Ext.application({
    models: [
        'Car'
    ],
    views: [
        'CascadingSelect'
    ],
    name: 'CascadingSelect',
    title: 'Some Title Here',

    requires: [
        'Ext.window.MessageBox'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('CascadingSelect.view.CascadingSelect');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be sufficient in your case to manually edit the file once and prevent SA from updating it?

Edit -> Project Settings -> General -> Untick 'Overwrite index file on save'

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm looking for a more permanent solution.  Right now I'm changing the title in the DOM.  The problem is that there are a few other DEV's on the project and I wanted to do something more permanent at the project level and not within the IDE.